# How to override the ant.core.lib location

Tags: java, ant

I am invoking Ant from some custom location and not from the "local" installation location
in my system (`/usr/share/ant/bin/ant`). Surprisingly when I echo the `${ant.core.lib}`
property, I see that Ant picks it up from /usr/share/lib regardless.

E.g. with the following build.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project name="foo" basedir=".">
    <echo message="ant.core.lib: ${ant.core.lib}"/>
</project>
```

This is what I see:

```
$ /some/other/location/apache/apache-ant-1.9.9/bin/ant
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM warning: ignoring option MaxPermSize=256m; support was removed in 8.0
Buildfile: /home/username/tmp/build.xml

    [echo] ant.core.lib: /usr/share/java/ant/ant.jar
```

Even when passing an alternate -lib location (where the other ant.jar lives) explicitly I still see the same:

```
$ /some/other/location/apache/apache-ant-1.9.9/bin/ant -lib /some/other/location/apache/apache-ant-1.9.9/lib
(same output as before)
```

How is Ant deciding how to set the value of the `${ant.core.lib}` property and where can I override it from so as to make Ant
use the ant.jar from some other location?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One would also have to set the environment variable ANT_HOME in the shell in such a case.
Then, `${ant.core.lib}` is picked up from `${ANT_HOME}/lib/ant.jar`.